# AppleScript SCPT corrupted file

Tags: applescript, corruption

I have an Applescript file that got corrupted and does not seem to be working anymore. I have tried almost everything and several script softwares, and none seemed to help.

What I would like to do, is recover (at least a part of) the script that could be read by Applescript Editor from my current scpt file. I have tried with osadecompile utility from Mac OS, but I get an error -1752 (errOSABadStorageType), and by looking at the scpt file, it seems to have stopped in the middle of it's execution (when it was supposed to grab file sizes and write them down in a Text file using TextEdit).

If possible, I would like to know if there is a tool that could read the beginning of this SCPT file and provide at least some partial code from what the original script was. It seems all other solutions require the full structure of a SCPT file to provide the final syntax.

Comment: Did you try Script Debugger (it has a demo version) ? I saw that it has a "Recover Damaged Script" command in the file menu.

Comment: Don't forget Time Machine.  I have recovered a few corrupted scripts over the years from my Time Machine repository.

Comment: @craig Unfortunately, Time Machine was off for this particular workstation... Maybe in the feature we will implement it.

Comment: @Zero Indeed I tried Script Debugger, but it didn't seemed to do anything.

Comment: @mboufleur - That is a real bummer.  I only turn mine on every week or so to catch up overnight, but it has saved me a few times over the years.  Best of luck with this.

Comment: @mboufleur - Do the guys at MacScripter a favor and edit your post to describe what you have already tried.